# Is it possible to remap Linked / Duplicate Keys? (D-Pad & Arrow Keys)

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout, touchpad

I have researched and tested, the various popularly recommended software, for keyboard re-mapping:

SharpKeys, KeyTweak, Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator, etc...

Of those that were able to detect my D-Pad key presses, they apparently still could not differentiate between the D-Pad, and the traditional directional Arrow Keys (Up, Down, Left, Right).

---

I recently got a new Keyboard (Logitech K600) that has a D-Pad near its top-right corner.

Image: [Logitech K600 (5)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wo3qz.jpg)

In addition to the 4 arrow directions, the center D-Pad key is linked to the [Enter] button.

For my purposes, those keys are redundant and not very useful, at least when used with my main laptop. Thus, I'd like to remap them to something like:

-> **Volume Up/Down - Forward/Back - Play/Pause (Enter)**

At the moment, I seem to be **unable to do this, without also remapping the traditional arrow keys** (and Enter button) at the same time.

For example, when using SharpKeys, KeyTweak... **exactly the same Key Code is returned**, when pressing either "**UP on Arrow Keys**", or "**UP on D-Pad**".

**Is there any known way that I can have the D-Pad and its linked (Arrow/Enter) traditional Keyboard buttons, be differentiated from each other?**

Thank you.

---

[Edit] The OS I am using is: "**Windows 10**"

---

[Edit] Just to add: I'm aware that in my situation, this particular keyboard does have dedicated buttons for Volume Up/Down, etc...
However, those are also at the Function Keys (F11, F12), which I use very frequently, and opted to override these Function keys as default.

Either way, the problem still remains, which is lack of flexibility in remapping these redundant/linked keys.

Comment: What OS are you using ? I think it is possible on Linux, but IDK about Windows or MacOS...

Comment: Good question. I'm using "Windows 10". (I'll add this info to original post)